# Application .exe Icon Different to Windows Explorer Icon

Tags: vb.net, icons, publish, windows-explorer

I recently changed my application icon at the end users request, by going into the project properties and and changing the icon under Application > Icon

The .exe, when built, has the correct logo next to it in the Windows Explorer folder, however, when clicking on the .exe once (Not running it, just selecting it), the old icon is visible.

To show what I mean, here is a screenshot from the end user.

[image]

The icon next to "Iconysis Agent.exe" is the correct one, but the one in the bottom left hand corner, which has been highlighted in yellow, is the old one that is still showing.

Is there somewhere that I've not changed it? I've looked through all of the tabs in the properties window, but can't see that it needs changing elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue found associated with Windows Explorer; what you've done has nothing to do with the program itself. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/351588/windows-7-folder-icons-cache-doesnt-refresh-when-icon-changed) on Superuser has a solution for it;

> You will need to delete your Icon Cache and reboot. Instructions can be found here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

(@Shevek's answer)

Comment: Ah, thanks. The end user isn't the most computer literate so I guess there will be a bit of explaining to do for them!